# EF: one to one relationship without generate new column using fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

every time I tried to add-migration and then it shows me the code like this:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Orders", "OrderItems_Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.Orders", "OrderItems_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Orders", "OrderItems_Id", "dbo.OrderItems", "Id");
    }
```

I seek the google and haven't found the solution,my entity belows,I want to set the OrderId of orderItems as a foreign key references by Orders.

```
    public class OrderItems
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public virtual Orders Order { get; set; }
}
    public class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderItems Order { get; set; }
}
```

My Fluent API looks like belows:

```
        public OrderItemsMapping()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        this.Property(x => x.GoodId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.OrderId).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Price).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Quantity).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.Score).IsRequired();

        this.HasOptional(x => x.Order)
.WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.OrderItems)
.Map(configurationAction: new Action<ForeignKeyAssociationMappingConfiguration>(x => x.MapKey()));

    }
```

another things I have to be mentioned is that **x.MapKey("Id")** will trigger error :Name had been set and it must be unique. thanks.

Comment: Whta is difference between `Id` and `OrderId`? If there is one-to-one relationship, then `OrderId` must be PK.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev thank you very much .I set the OrderId as key and it solved my problem.

Comment: Ok, then let me add this as answer. IMHO it will be better if you also change `Optional` to `Required` in FK mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said that, there is one-to-one relationship between `Order` and `OrderItem` entities. If this is the case, then `OrderId` must be primary key in the `OrderItem` entity.

Also,  your entity's names shouldbe named in singular rather than plural by convention.

As a result, your entities must look like:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderId { get; set;}

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderItem OrderItem { get; set; }
}
```

And `OrderItem` mapping:

```
// Primary Key
this.HasKey(m => m.OrderId);

...
this.HasRequired(m => m.Order)
    .WithRequiredDependent(m => m.OrderItem);
...
```